Was bedeutet "oder wie?" als Fragewörter am Satzende?
Nochmal aus QualityLand von Kling:

 "Diese Nanny beherrscht vier verschiedene Kampfkünste", hatte sie
Martyn erklärt, "und kann unser Mädchen vor Kinderschändern
schützen.""Warum vier Kampfkünste?", hatte Martyn gefragt.
 "Falls der Kinderschänder Karate kann, kann sie ihm immer noch mit
Kung-Fu kommen, oder wie? Das ist doch lächerlich."

Ich glaube, ich habe diese Art "oder wie" schon mal gehört oder gelesen, und habe immer angenommen, dass es einfach eine längere Version von "oder?" ist. Ich bin mir aber nicht sicher und es fällt einem schwer, eine genaue Definition im Internet zu finden. Oder wird es hier vielleicht als Abkürzung von "oder wie auch immer" benutzt? Ich weiß nicht. Ich wäre euch für eure Hilfe dankbar.

Ich würde dieses "..., oder wie?" als eine Refrainfrage sehen. Refrainfragen sind kurze Fragen, die an einen Aussagesatz angehängt werden. Ein häufiges Beispiel ist "..., nicht wahr?"
Wörtlich kann man dieses "oder wie?" als eine Kurzform verstehen von etwas wie "..., oder wie soll ich das verstehen?" oder "..., oder wie hast Du Dir das gedacht?". In der Regel hat es aber einen spöttischen Unterton, der das zuvor Gesagte ins Lächerliche ziehen soll. Der Sprecher sagt ja auch direkt danach, "Das ist doch lächerlich."

Danke Henning - gibt es eine Funktion von "oder wie", bei der der Ausdruck nicht spöttisch wäre?

@cruthers Es kann auch Verwirrung ausdrücken, etwa in "Wir gehen erst ins Restaurant und dann ins Kino, oder erst ins Kino und dann ins Restaurant, oder wie?". Es ist in jedem Fall eine implizite Nachfrage. Ob diese Nachfrage nun ernst gemeint ist, oder eher ironisch oder spöttisch, muss man dann dem Kontext entnehmen.
